# Url is missing from appinsights logs for requests

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I cannot see URL in azure-appinsights for any Request which I made through my azure-function endpoint. Below are the steps and description to explain the issues

1. Run any number of load on sandbox
2. Go to appinsights -> Logs
3. Query for the following -
   `requests | where cloud_RoleName contains "test" | order by duration desc | project itemType, cloud_RoleName, url, appName, timestamp, name, cloud_RoleInstance.`

What I've observed is - If my azure function **Startup** class inherit from **IWebJobStartup** then we are getting URL for request in appinsights logs, but if **Startup** class inherit from **FunctionStartup** we are not getting Url in appinsights logs.

*Image of App Insights for your reference*

[image: URL_Missing_AppInsights]

We want to use FunctionStartup as we have written so much code based upon that in so many services. And we want to use constructor DI which is not possible in IWebJobStartup (as per the sample which I have).

1. Getting URL in appinsight logs if we use below code in startup class

```
namespace TestApplicationWebJob.Infrastructure
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    internal class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        static string appInstanceId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            #pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            builder.AddDependencyInjection(ConfigureServices);
            builder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), opts =>
            {
```

2. Not getting URL in appinsights logs, if we use below code in startup class

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace TestApplicationFunc.Infrastructure
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            RegisterServices(builder.Services);

            builder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), opts =>
            {
                opts.SpecVersion = OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0;
                opts.Documents = new[]
                {
                    new SwaggerDocument
                    {
```

project config XML
.csproj file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For `FunctionsStartup`, we need to override the `Configure` method as

`public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)`
as you have already done.

Even I have faced the same issue with the Isolated .NET 5 Azure function.
I have tried it by downgrading this dependency to v3, and the function worked.
Try to create Azure Functions v3 project and .NET Core 3.1 library while inheriting from FunctionsStartup in Startup class.
For reference please check the [MS Document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services)

Comment: Hi @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT, I have update the post with the project configuration. My application is with azure function v3 with .net core 3.1. Still URL is not showing in AppInsights Request.

Comment: @GhanshyamDhanore, Do you have this extension in your project references - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. If having, which version it belongs to?

Comment: No. It's not exist in project.

Comment: can you try once by including the Microsoft.extensions.configuration package reference of version 3.x.x or by downgradign the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus package version to 3.x.x

Comment: after downgrading packages still It's not working.